# iCloud.com has empty picture folder

Tags: icloud, photos

Using the Finder on my iMac, I goto the iCloud Drive. There is a Pictures folder showing 5.78 GB. Inside the Pictures folder are 2 files: "iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary" and "Photos Library.photoslibrary".  These total 5.78 GB as expected.  I logged onto iCloud.com and went to the iCloud Drive folder. The folder names matched what was displayed using Finder. Opening the Pictures folder however revealed it was empty. Why did this folder show empty on iCloud.com but showed over 5GB using Finder?  A similar question has been asked but not answered. I thought I would try my luck.

The 2 files shown in Finder both are designated with a cloud with a line drawn thru it. When I hover the mouse over that small icon it says ineligible.  Any clue whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photos library is not synchronised to iCloud Drive as itself. Rather, Photos syncs the *contents* of the library to iCloud to appear in the Photos section of iCloud.com. This means the library itself won't appear in the Pictures folder on iCloud.

Comment: Is this how it should be and where are my photos actually stored?

Comment: I suppose all my 'pictures' are in Photos now?

Comment: @john This is standard for iCloud, the ‘ineligible’ flag is set by the OS for the library marked as the system photo library. The photos on your machine are stored in the library, but on iCloud they are stored in the separate Photos ‘service’ of iCloud Photo Library ([iCloud.com/photos](https://www.icloud.com/photos)).

Comment: @john Definitely no stupidity here, no worries!